# How to change wifi proxy android programmatically?

Tags: android, proxy

I need to change the proxy of connected wifi with code or programmatically, I tried any possible solution in stack overflow but it didnt work because of WifiManager is depracated.

Can anybody have solution using WifiNetworkSpecifier?